# Postgresql Update a unique column and validate before Update

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, validation

**Scenario:** an admin user insert a new client on DB, it has 3 uniques columns, postgres id, something like driver license, and an email, later on I'm trying to allow the admin user to update those fields BUT when i run the validation of course it returns false, cause they already exist, I [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166127/symfony-updating-unique-column-validation-problem) and is the same issue but I ain't running symfony or any other PHP framework, i figured i could try to send the id within the query and check against id and email for instance but since is a live validation i just send the input value.

**Solution 1:** Don't allow admin user to update those fields and have him to delete the client and create a new one (this is the easy getaway).

**Solution 2?** I can't think on any logic, how can i build a query to validate on this issue?

**something like:**

```
SELECT email FROM users.users WHERE email=$email AND id != $id ???
```

The problem is that i can't figured out how to send the ID within the input field... this is my validation code:

```
email: {
            trigger: 'blur',
            message: 'El email no es válido',
            validators: {
                remote: {
                    message: 'Ya existe un usuario con ese email',
                    url: 'actions/chk_available.php',
                    data: {
                        type: 'email'
                    },
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            }
        },
```

This code runs on server side when the admin user leave the field.

**UPDATE**

Let's say i got 2 rows:

1. email: aaa@host.com
2. email: bbb@host.com

   SELECT COUNT (1) FROM users.users_web WHERE email=$email

If admin user is Updating the second row and doesn't touch the email, everything is good, if he update the email with the same value as row 1(aaa@host.com) That query validate as valid because still being count 1 and the update will end filling 2 identical emails, but postgresql is not gonna allow because is a unique field, so that's where it gets all messy.

Comment: just SELECT count(1) FROM users.users WHERE email=$email, if count>1 raise error

Comment: with that query I always going to end up having error because the user already exists, my goal is to be able to update the email if the user changed it or just leave the field with the same value if the user doesn't change it, this query gives me an error if the user don't change the email.

Comment: if I get you  right - update email by id if changed, not updated if the same?.. so anyway you have to compare emails -old against one. so you always have some value in email. so just ALWAYS UPDATE... If value changed, you have new email, if not - same (old)

Comment: I know, but the problem is not updating the email or not, you are right about that and i understand that, the problem is validating before i send the form, maybe i'll update the question to see if i can make it more clear.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of your query to see if i can make myself more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother trying to "pre-validate" unique constraints. Just write to the db and catch violations. It's faster and more correct. Trying to "pre-validate" is a race condition anyway.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f4a0/1

Comment: Ok I think I follow, so when ppl try to update i catch the error from the database itself? ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_email_key" Detail: Key (email)=(bbb@host.com) already exists.

Comment: @user1212548 yes. You can catch the error and show a more friendly error message